# Analyzing a non linear circuit with two sources

Tags: circuit-analysis, non-linear

I want to analyze this circuit. V1 is a) +15V b) +10V c) -5V

I need V2, V3, I1, I2, I3

Uz=6,8V
UF=0,7V

And I hate to say this, but I'm absolutely lacking any approach. I don't know how to manage V1.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhZXs0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Use KVL and Uf or Uz to solve if forward or reverse biased then Ohm’s Law works too from the voltage differences

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to describe the diodes. They are ideal. I edited my question.

Comment: You keep asking very similar questions about analyzing circuits with diodes. By now you should have some idea how to start one of these problems. Haven't you made any progress on your own?

Comment: You have already put the circuit to the schematic editor of this site. You can also use it to analyze (=simulate) the circuit.